# Bootstrap scss utilities map extending not working

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

I am trying to extend bootstrap color utilities provided by their utilities api offical [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/)

```
$utilities: map-merge(
    $utilities,
    ( 
      "color": map-merge(
        map-get($utilities, "color"),
        (
          values: map-merge(
            map-get(map-get($utilities, "color"), "values"),
            map-merge($blues,$indigos)
          ),
        )
      )
    )
);
```

when I do this, this file has access to bootstrap all variables for colors and mixins, functions etc. and this is working fine.

However when I try to add third parameter in map-merge function for extending color utility like this,

```
map-merge($blues,$indigos,$purples)
```

it gives me error which is very weird as it should work same in case of two.

> ("indigo-100": #e0cffc, "indigo-200": #c29ffa, "indigo-300": #a370f7,
> "indigo-400": #8540f5, "indigo-500": #6610f2, "indigo-600": #520dc2,
> "indigo-700": #3d0a91, "indigo-800": #290661, "indigo-900": #140330)
> isn't a valid CSS value.
>
> $property-class-modifier: if($key, if($property-class == "" and $infix
> == "", "", "-") + $key, "");

Is this due to any size limitation on utilities or scss native `map-merge` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scss `map-merge` function is only able to merge two maps at a time hence third parameter was not allowed.

So in this specific case we can use the `map-merge-multiple` function provided in [_function.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_functions.scss#L100) file of bootstrap library (Line no 100) for merging multiple maps together.

```
@function map-merge-multiple($maps...) {
  $merged-maps: ();

  @each $map in $maps {
    $merged-maps: map-merge($merged-maps, $map);
  }
  @return $merged-maps;
}
```

Function is also self explanatory.

> All it does is that it first takes all maps as an argument, then
> declares one empty map inside the function for merging purpose and
> loop through all maps, updates that empty map with `map-merge`on each
> iteration (because here only two maps will be there at a time) and
> finally returns that map which is `$merged-maps` which will be merged
> entry of each maps.

So in above case it will become

```
$utilities: map-merge(
    $utilities,
    ( 
      "color": map-merge(
        map-get($utilities, "color"),
        (
          values: map-merge(
            map-get(map-get($utilities, "color"), "values"),
            map-merge-multiple($blues,$indigos,$purples)
          ),
        )
      )
    )
);
```

which works perfectly fine now.